# ¿cómo hacer que IE reconozca la palabra reservada LET?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Tengo un plugin de javascript en donde requiero de utilizar una variable con la palabra **let** 
pero en Internet explorer 11 no reconoce esa palabra y me marca un error, a diferencia de los demás sitios

Y si cambio la palabra por var, el código ya no funciona de la forma correcta

quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer entender a IE11 esta sintaxis

intenté poniendo el meta en la página

pero sigue saliendo el error

Comment: nadie entiende IE ni siquiera Microsoft IE tiene una version antigua de JavaScript por ello  [let no la puedes usar](https://caniuse.com/#search=let) , pero puedes hacer un truco, puedes usar [babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) para transpilar tu codigo pero esto es a nivel de JS, faltarian los css que es otro dolor de cabeza :(

Comment: :( rayoos, esa no me la sabia, vale e intentado transpilar mi código con babel, pero la forma que me proporciona babel, no realiza mi código lo que necesito

Comment: Digamos que la palabra LET es algo que requiero para que me código siga funcionando cómo debe

Comment: Puedes revisar mi respuesta que te deje más abajo.

Comment: No puedes obligar al navegador algo si no lo tiene let salio en la [version EcmaScript 2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) y  hasta [IE10  no lo soporta](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#ie10) IE 11 lo soporta con un "*" asi que probablemente estes usando IE <= 10

Comment: Ok entiendo, gracias ;)

Comment: voto por cerrar esta pregunta como *Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos.* ya que Internet Explorer no tiene la palabra reservada `let` por ende esta pregunta contiene errores tipograficos; tambien deje una explicacion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La palabra reservada de `let` no es soportada por varios navegadores, dado que es algo nuevo de `ecmascript` con suerte algunas versiones de `Chrome` y otras de `Firefox` las soportan en forma nativa, pero si tu alcance es más global sobre todo para usarla por medio de `IE` es imposible ya que este browser no brinda este soporte.

> Desde MDN indican que no se debería usar directamente desde un browser por el soporte.

**¿COMO LO PUEDO SOLUCIONAR?**

La mejor técnica es transpilar tu código que no soporta `IE` usando [babel](https://babeljs.io/), esto te va a generar un nuevo código de él cual tu navegador podrá entender.

Comment: Ok gracias por el consejo ;)+

Comment: de nada. Saludos !.

Comment: ¿Quien me voto negativo? que me explique el por que. Gracias.

Comment: yo no fui, la cuestion es que respondistes lo que escribi en el comentario, salvo que complementes mi comentario  se comprenderia tu respuesta

Comment: ah... en todo caso cuando comente recién vi que era similar a lo que habías indicado. Pero en fin ambas respuesta son válidas.

Comment: por cierto acabo de probar let en IE11 y si funciona, entonces el OP no usa IE11

Comment: yo te voté negativo, tu respuesta es solo un comentario a mi parecer, el primer párrafo es algo genérico y la solución es solo un enlace

Comment: Para mí la respuesta es correcta. Por cierto, babel transforma algo como `let a = 1;` a `var a = 1;` Quizá no estaría de mas agregar algunos ejémplos.

Comment: @Aprendiz si mi solución es un alcance ¿para ti cual seria la solución?

Comment: no tiene solucion directa, no puedes obligar a IE que acepte let

Comment: Si babel transpila JS de *let* a *var* y el OP dice que *var* le complica la existencia, entonces no es una solución.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Pero es una posible solución VALIDA ahora si la toma quien formulo la pregunta o no, o si es una respuesta valida, es él. Por ende no deja de ser una respuesta.

Comment: *quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer entender a IE11 esta sintaxis*: No la hay y no la habrá. Babel es un recurso que debes saber usar. Babel no hará que IE entienda ECMA Script 5 o superior, Babel solo tomará el código (escrito en ES5+) y lo convertirá (transpilar) en código compatible con IE. Esa es la razón por la cuál la respuesta a la pregunta inicial de este comentario es la que doy: *no hay forma ni manera que IE entienda let*, y en la versión 11, el soporte no es completo, por lo cual se aconseja no usar *let*. Saludos

Comment: La única opción de OP es "complicarse la vida" con var, de otra manera es imposible. En dicha complicación, Babel puede ser una opción que OP deberá investigar. Dicho sea de paso, los usuarios de IE 11 están acostumbrados a ver todo con errores, así que la app de OP parecerá normal : )

Comment: @vcasas te invito al [chat].